# Symfony2 change type of collection field with Ajax

Tags: ajax, symfony, inheritance, collections

In my project Symfony2, I have an entity `Projet` with relation (1,n) with the entity `TypeConstruction`.
An object `TypeConstruction` can be an object `Immeuble` or `Villa`...
So the object `Immeuble` inherit the object `TypeConstruction` ...

The code of the entity `TypeConstruction`:

```
 /**


* @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="typeconstruction")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="typeFille", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap( {"typeConstruction" = "TypeConstruction", "lotissement" = "Lotissement", "immeuble" = "Immeuble", "appartement" = "Appartement", "villa" = "Villa", "piece" = "Piece"} )
 */ 
class TypeConstruction
{


/**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="numLot", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $numLot;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=1000)
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="superficie", type="float")
 */
private $superficie;

/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="longueur", type="float")
 */
private $longueur;

/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="largeur", type="float")
 */
private $largeur;

/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="hauteur", type="float")
 */
private $hauteur;

/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="millieme", type="float")
 */
private $millieme;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Immo\IntervenantBundle\Entity\Proprietaire", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
*/
private $proprietaires;


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Immo\DossierBundle\Entity\Projet", inversedBy="typeConstructions")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
*/
private $projet;

private $typeFille ;

//getter setter
.....}
```

The code of entity `Immeuble`:

```
class Immeuble extends TypeConstruction
{

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nbreBloc", type="integer")
 */
private $nbreBloc;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nbreEtage", type="integer")
 */
private $nbreEtage;

/**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Immo\TypeConstructionBundle\Entity\Lotissement")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
 private $lotissement;

 /**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Immo\TypeConstructionBundle\Entity\Type")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
*/
private $type;

/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Immo\TypeConstructionBundle\Entity\Bloc", mappedBy="immeuble")
*/
private $blocs;
...}
```

The code of entity `Projet`:

```
class Projet
{

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Code", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $code;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Description", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="DateDebutPrev", type="datetime")
 */
private $dateDebutPrev;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="DateFinPrev", type="datetime")
 */
private $dateFinPrev;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="DateDebutReel", type="datetime",nullable=true)
 */
private $dateDebutReel;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="DateFinReel", type="datetime",nullable=true)
 */
private $dateFinReel;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="NbreBatiment", type="integer")
 */
private $nbreBatiment;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="NbreEtage", type="integer",nullable=true)
 */
private $nbreEtage;


/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Immo\TypeConstructionBundle\Entity\TypeConstruction", cascade={"persist"}, mappedBy="projet")
*/
private $typeConstructions;
...}
```

In my forms I do this in `TypeConstructionType`:

```
class TypeConstructionType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('numLot')
        ->add('description')
        ->add('superficie')
        ->add('longueur')
        ->add('largeur')
        ->add('hauteur')
        ->add('millieme')
        ->add('typeFille', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array(
                        "lotissement" => "Lotissement", 
                        "immeuble" => "Immeuble", 
                        "appartement" => "Appartement", 
                        "villa" => "Villa", 
                        "piece" => "Piece"

             ),
                'required'    => false,
                'empty_value' => 'Veuillez choisir',
                'empty_data'  => null
        ))

    ;
}...}
```

The code of `ImmeubleType`:

```
class ImmeubleType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('nbreBloc')
        ->add('nbreEtage')
        ->add('type', 'entity', array(
          'class'    => 'ImmoTypeConstructionBundle:Type',
          'query_builder' => function(TypeRepository $repo) {
                return $repo->getTypeOfTypeConstruction('immeuble');
          },
          'empty_value' => 'Veuillez choisir',

          'property' => 'type',
          'multiple' => false
        ))
        ->add('blocs', 'collection', array(
            'type'         => new BlocType(),
            'prototype' => true,
            'allow_add'    => true,
      ))
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Immo\TypeConstructionBundle\Entity\Immeuble'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'immo_typeconstructionbundle_immeuble';
}

public function getParent()
{
    return new TypeConstructionType();
}
}
```

The code of `ProjetType`:

```
class ProjetType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('code','text')
        ->add('description','text')
        ->add('dateFinPrev','date')
         ->add('dateDebutPrev', 'date', array(
              'widget' => 'single_text',
              'input' => 'datetime',
              'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
              ))
        ->add('dateDebutReel','date')
         ->add('dateFinPrev', 'date', array(
              'widget' => 'single_text',
              'input' => 'datetime',
              'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
              ))
        ->add('dateFinReel','date')
        ->add('nbreBatiment')
        ->add('nbreEtage')



        ->add('typeConstructions', 'collection', array(
            'type'         => new TypeConstructionType(),
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'allow_delete' => true
          ))


    ;
}...}
```

In the view of add projet, I have:

```
<div class="bloc" id="formTypeConstruction">                        

    <div id="immo_dossierbundle_projet_typeConstructions" data-prototype="{% filter escape %}{% include 'ImmoTypeConstructionBundle:TypeConstruction:new.html.twig' with {'formTCAdd': form.typeConstructions.vars.prototype} %}{% endfilter %}">
    </div>
</div><!--bloc-->
```

In the `ImmoTypeConstructionBundle:TypeConstruction:new.html.twig`, I have the code to show a select list of typeConstruction (Immeuble, Villa....):

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="formulaire">
        <div>
            <label class="col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2 control-label" for="textinput">Type de construction</label>
             <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                 {{form_widget(formTCAdd.typeFille,{'attr':{'class': 'form-control selectpicker'}})}}
             </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

In the form of adding a `Projet`, I want to select the `TypeConstruction` from the list select and with Ajax the form of `ImmeubleType` will be displayed if I choise the type `Immeuble`.

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: did you find a way to solve your question? I have a similar case: when I choose a value in a select tag, I would like to display a collection Type of form. But the formType depend of the select choice.